# Column breaks Align

Tags: flutter

I don't understand why but when I add `Column` to `Align` in `Stack` positioning breaks

```
 Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
              ....
        ),
        Align(  /// <-- doesn't work
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Column(
              children: [
                  Widget...
                  Widget...
              ]
        ),),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Text('text')
        ),]),
```

with `Column` widgets are placed top left

Comment: Try changing `mainAxisSize` property of Column to `MainAxisSize.min`

Comment: @SahilSonawane nice, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Stack, all elements are located at the top left.
In order to control the position for widgets you need to use the Positioned.

```
 Positioned(
   right: 0,
   bottom: 0,
   child: Your Widget(),
 ),
```

This code example will place the widget in the stack at the bottom right

Or you can add this parameters in Column:

```
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   children: [],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to test following solutions:

- Wrap `Column` with `Expanded`
- Change `mainAxisSize` parameter of `Column` widget to minimal
- Wrap `Stack` with `Expanded`
- Wrap each `Stack` child with `Expanded`
  if neither of that is gonna work, i would try to combine some of that...

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
              ....
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, /// <-solution
              children: [
                  Widget...
                  Widget...
              ]
        ),),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Text('text')
        ),]),
```